# How do I force a folder to be opened in column view in Finder?

Tags: finder

I'll try to give a general example.

I have the following folder structure somewhere on my local user directory:

```
Root_Folder
├── Icon_Folder
│   ├── file1
│   └── file6
└── Column_Folder
    ├── file10
    ├── file11
    └── file12
```

How can I force Finder to open the `Column_Folder/` in column view while forcing the `Icon_Folder/` (and other possible folders) to be viewed in icon view?

---

Sounds trivial, yes, but here's where I have problems:

- I open `Icon_Folder/`, change its view to icon view, press <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> and tick "Always open in icon view" — presto! it works.
- Then I open `Column_Folder/`, change its view to column view, double–check the Finder window's title bar reads "Column_Folder", open view options again — but wait! Finder wants to change the view settings for `~/Desktop/`, not `Column_Folder/`!

NB: I know it specifically wants to change Desktop's view settings because that is where the `Root_Folder/` is. If I move the `Root_Folder/` to `~/`, Finder would like to change, while in column view, the view settings for my home directory and so on…

I'd rather like to know a GUI answer, but if it is much easier via command line, it's OK by me.

All in all, the question boils down to: **How do I open the active folder's view settings in Finder while browsing in column view?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Workaround

1. While in Finder (in any view) drag the `Column_Folder/` to the Finder's sidebar.
2. Select the `Column_Folder/` from the sidebar
3. Switch to column view
4. Show view settings

   - You can see the view settings will now affect the intended folder
5. Tick "Always open in column view"; click OK
6. Remove `Column_Folder/` from the sidebar

Now `Column_Folder/` will open in column view!

Comment: I decided to accept this as it works, but if someone can come up with a more elegant solution, I'm willing to accept it.

Comment: This works because Column View looks at the current folder and finds its closest ancestor in the sidebar, and chooses that folder as the leftmost column. You can force a folder to *open* in CV by checking "Always open…" and "Browse…" in the View Options. You can force it to be the *root* of CV by placing it in the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if a folder is not shown in the sidebar, it won't usually be the root folder of any window in column view.

Also "Always open in column view" means "save a folder-specific view mode for this folder in the `.DS_Store` file of the parent folder". If you check "Always open in column view" and switch to list view, the folder-specific view mode becomes list view.

So if you add `~/Desktop/untitled folder/` to the sidebar, open `untitled folder`, and check "Always open in column view", the folder-specific view mode is saved to `~/Desktop/.DS_Store`. If you remove `~/Desktop/untitled folder/` from the sidebar, it will never be the root folder of a column view window. But if you open `~/Desktop/untitled folder/` in list view and close the window, the folder-specific view mode becomes list view.